# Can one import a DialogFlow agent into LUIS

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I have a fully mature agent in DialogFlow with utterances, intents and entities.  Is there a way to quickly bring this info over into a new app in Luis?  I really don't want to reenter the information.  I know DialogFlow allows for a zip export.  Is this format recognized by Luis?

Answer (score 0):

This format is not recognised per Luis but both Dialogflow and luis have APIs and you can use those APIs to extract the utterances from Dialogflow and then POST those into Luis

Comment: So you are talking about [this](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0c) iterating overall all my intents?

Comment: Yes! At least this is what i would do :)